# Callback function leads to infinity loop error in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, callback

I am new to react native and simply can not find the reason for the infinity loop error I spent my last few hours with... Here is what is happening:

I have the following custom component

```
import { TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, View, Text } from "react-native";
import { FontAwesome } from "@expo/vector-icons";

function AnswerContainer_CheckBox(props) {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

const checkedHandler =()=>{
  if (checked == false) {
    setChecked(true);
  } else {
    setChecked(false);
  }
}
  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
         checkedHandler();
         props.true_1;
          }
        }
      >
        <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
          <View style={styles.icon}>
            <FontAwesome
              name={checked == true ? "check-square" : "square-o"}
              size={24}
              color={checked == true ? "#3787FF" : "#BFD3E5"}
            />
          </View>
          <Text style={styles.checkButtonText}>{props.title}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

I use that Component in my screen like this:

```
function myScreen(props) {

  const [true1, setTrue1] = useState(false);

  const setTrue_1_Handler = () => {
    switch (true1) {
      case false:
        setTrue1(true);
        alert("true");
        break;
      case true:
        setTrue1(false);
        break;
    }
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <AnswerContainer_CheckBox true_1={setTrue_1_Handler()} title="Test_1" />
      <AnswerContainer_CheckBox title="Test_2" />
      <AnswerContainer_CheckBox title="Test_3" />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Whenever I navigate to "myScreen", the infite loop error apperas and crashes the app - even though I didn't press that button yet.

Any ideas? I know the issue has come up a few times but I still didn't make it work (useEffect didn't help somehow...).

Thanks

Comment: why you call the function setTrue_1_Handler(); you should pass the reference of function, but you call the function in props;  change: setTrue_1_Handler() to setTrue_1_Handler

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! Changing true_1={setTrue_1_Handler()} into  true_1={setTrue_1_Handler} stops the loop but won't execute the function. Nothing happens onPress :-(

Comment: Hello, and: in the component: change:       props.true_1; to props.true_1( )

Comment: You are a mastermind! It worked! Thanks :-D

Comment: happy to help you ;)

Comment: Damn I do get a different error now :/ "props.true_1 is not a function. (in 'props.true_1();, props.true_1' is undefined"

Comment: console.log props and tell me is there any function in there

Comment: why you just assign the  true_1={setTrue_1_Handler} just to first one; so it works for the first one; please comment the second usage of your component and check it

Comment: I think I found the issue (but don't know how to solve it): I have three instances of AnswerContainer_CheckBox. The Component has the props.true_1(), props.true_2() and props.true_3(). So when I click on the first instance of the component on my screen, the props.true_2() and props.true_3() remain empty causing the error... :-(